# ios cross dissolve segue transition color?

Tags: ios, xcode, transition, segue

I can't seem to find anything on the web about this, but is it possible to make apples segue cross dissolve transition a certain color? Links or examples welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant make the actual transition change color. To achieve that you need to do it manually, for example:

If you want the modal from scene1 to scene2 to be modal with cross dissolve transition. Make the scene2 have a blue rectangle covering the screen. On `-(void)viewDidAppear;` You start an animation that changes the alpha of the rectangle from 1 to 0.

If you want an even better transition, make a modal without any animations. On the scene1, when the segue is going to happen make the rectangle appear from 0 ro 1 alpha.

This is just one example, you can play around with animations and do your own transition in any way you want.